# Using variables between a couple of files

Tags: php, html, file

*I found this a little hard to explain, so if there's any unclear part please let me know.*

I'm making a single player web RPG.

I have a few files:

`characters.php`: this one contains the `character` class, along with its methods (`levelUp()` for example)

`create1.php`: this is the page in which the user chooses the character's attributes, and then the character is created.
it includes this part:

```
    require 'characters.php';
    $player = new Character($race);
    $player->levelUp();
```

What happens here: the user is taken to `create1.php` and enters their race, and with the user's input a new `character` is created.

Now we have the `$player` variable which contains all the character information, and it's stored within the `create1.php` file.

What I intend is to `require` `characters.php` in every single page of the web game. This means I have to import `$player` into `characters.php`. 
In other words, I have to move `$player` into a page which will be present in ALL of the game's pages, because it contain's the user's character data.

How can I achieve this **without** creating the new instance of `character` in `characters.php`, but in `create1.php`?

Comment: answer: using a database and fetching on demand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use database (as suggests STT LCU in the comment) or `$_SESSION` with lazy init

in **characters.php**

```
session_start();
function getCharacter() {
  if(!isset($_SESSION["player"])) $_SESSION["player"] = new Character(...);
  return $_SESSION["player"];
}
```

in **other files**

```
require 'characters.php';
$player = getCharacter(); // create instance or get existing one if exists
```

Comment: Database it shall be then, but I'm happy that you've also shown another way.

Comment: @frrlod it is the same, just instead of `new Character();` do the DB queries to build the data. Or even better: place the DB queries into the Character class - it is called model.

Answer (score 2):

[STT LCU](https://stackoverflow.com/users/998759/stt-lcu) is right on this one. The canonical solution to what you're trying to do is to use a database. Look into running an [AMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Apache%E2%80%93MySQL%E2%80%93PHP_packages) stack on your machine and use a SQL database to store your data. Pull the data from the database on each page as you require it with `SELECT` queries.

Alternatively, assuming only one user and one character will be accessing it at a time, you can save the character data into a text file, and open and read the text file back into a `character` object in each of your PHP files. This might have less of a learning curve for what you're trying to do.

*edit* PHP session can be used but will expire (with the data inside it) when the browser closes or after the default time of 24 minutes (I believe.)